# Cassandra Cannot locate storage-conf.xml

Tags: java, cassandra, freebsd

I was trying to start Cassandra on FreeBSD with /usr/local/share/cassandra/bin/cassandra.
But it gives me the following error messages, any idea how to get around the problem? Any suggestions will be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

INFO 21:16:38,666 JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
ERROR 21:16:38,684 Exception encountered during startup.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:73)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:224)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot locate storage-conf.xml via storage-config system property or classpath lookup.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:584)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot locate storage-conf.xml via storage-config system property or classpath lookup.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getStorageConfigPath(DatabaseDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:187)
    ... 2 more
Exception encountered during startup.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:73)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:224)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot locate storage-conf.xml via storage-config system property or classpath lookup.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:584)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot locate storage-conf.xml via storage-config system property or classpath lookup.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getStorageConfigPath(DatabaseDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:187)
    ... 2 more

Comment: this looks promising: http://journal.paul.querna.org/articles/2010/11/11/enabling-jna-in-cassandra/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this cassandra 0.6.x?  You probably want to upgrade to the latest cassandra, 0.7.4

The error is because Cassandra can't locate storage-conf.xml.  This file should be in your cassandra conf directory, see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration

If you upgrade to cassandra 0.7.x, you will need a cassandra.yaml file instead.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Thanks a lot.